# Is there a standard HTTP header servers use to exchange JWTs with clients?

Tags: http, jwt

I'm in the process of writing a client and server for an application and I'm wondering if there are any standard/established HTTP headers that servers can use to:

- Communicate new/updated JWT data
- Receive the JWT from the client

I'm having a difficult time getting results on this because the term "header" is ambiguous with JWT in an HTTP context.

Comment: Seems likely to be [`Authorization`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.8), which the JWT spec [passively agrees with](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html#Introduction) -- "*intended for space constrained environments such as **HTTP Authorization headers** and URI query parameters.*"

Comment: Has any convention/spec been established for the server to communicate an updated JWT as a header as part of a response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JWT is really just a format for passing signed and/or encrypted data about. Standard headers would most likely be part of a protocol specification instead.

Examples where JWT is used as part of a specification include Mozilla Persona/BrowserID and OpenID Connect, but in these the tokens are generally transferred as part of Ajax requests or occasionally in a URL fragment (for the OpenID Connect [IdToken](http://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-multiple-response-types-1_0.html#id_token)).

For something like OAuth 2.0 [Bearer authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) JWT could be a useful option (and is used in some implementations), but the spec doesn't actually say what the token should be. It could equally well be an opaque value linked to some back-end storage.

So I don't believe there are any standard headers specifically designed to hold JWTs - it would depend on the context in which they were being used.